# Why does GNU parallel affect script speed?

Tags: performance, optimization, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have some Fortran script. I compile with `gfortran` and then run as `time ./a.out`.

My script completes, and outputs the runtime as,

```
real 0m36.037s
user 0m36.028s
sys 0m0.004s
```

i.e. ~36 seconds

Now suppose I want to run this script multiple times, in parallel. For this I am using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Using the `lscpu` command tells me that I have 8 CPUs, with 2 threads per core and 4 cores per socket.

I create some file `example.txt` of the form,

```
time ./a.out
time ./a.out
time ./a.out
time ./a.out
...
```

which goes on for 8 lines.

I can then run these in parallel on 8 cores as,

```
parallel -j 8 :::: example.txt
```

In this case I would expect the runtime for each script to still be 36 seconds, and the total runtime to be ~36 seconds. However, in actuality what happens is the run time for each script roughly doubles.

If I instead run on 4 cores instead of 8 (`-j 4`) the problem disappears, and each script reverts to taking 36 seconds to run.

**What is the cause of this?** I have heard talk in the past on 'overheads' but I am not sure exactly what is meant by this.

Comment: I suspect you have 4 HT (hyperthreaded) CPUs which Intel sells as 8 but are actually partially shared and no use as a core when your load is 100% CPU-bound which your `sys` time implies is the case. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that you have only one socket with `4` physical cores in it.
Those are the *real* cores of your machine.
The total number of CPUs you see as output of `lscpu` is calculated using the following formula: `#sockets * #cores_per_socket * #threads_per_core`.
In your case it is `1*4*2=8`.

Threads per core are a sort of *virtual* CPUs and they do not always perform as real CPUs, expecially for compute intense processing (this spec is called [hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) ).
Hence when you try to squeeze two threads per core, they get almost executed serially.

[Take a look at this article for more info.](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-core-i5,2410-5.html)